# Function Not Firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I have two select tags that show/ hide divs based on dropdown selection. I can't figure out why I can get them to work independently of each other but not together.

I've console.log both functions and the function called first in my main.js is the only one called. Am I exporting and importing my functions wrong?

I'm using Webpack to bundle my code together.

index.html

```
<select id="create-PO">
  <option value="la">LA</option>
  <option value="nyc">NYC</option>
</select>

<div id="la" class="create-PO-location">
  West Coast
</div>

<div id="nyc" class="create-PO-location">
 East Coast
</div>


<select id="create-season">
  <option value="summer">SUMMER</option>
  <option value="winter">WINTER</option>
</select>


<div id="summer" class="create-PO-man">
  IT'S SUMMER
</div>

<div id="winter" class="create-PO-man">
 IT'S WINTER
</div>
```

scss

```
.create-PO-man, .create-PO-location{
   display:none;
}
```

drop-down-show.js

```
export function dropDown1(){
  $("#create-PO").on("change",function(){
    $(".create-PO-location").hide();
    $("#" + $(this).val()).fadeIn(700);
  }).change();
}

export function dropDown2(){
  $("#create-season").on("change",function(){
    $(".create-PO-man").hide();
    $("#" + $(this).val()).fadeIn(700);
   }).change();
 }
```

main.js

```
import {dropDown1, dropDown2 } from "./scripts/drop-down-show";

dropDown1();
dropDown2();
```

Comment: Browsers provide the module path to include the filename extension too.

Comment: Check your value (LA) and the id (la) not uppercase

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure you need to export them as an object:

```
export {dropDown1, dropDown2};
```

Comment: Edited the answer a bit, because as far as I know when exporting in this way you are exporting things as an object.

Comment: It doesn't export "an object" but conceptually you can think of it that way. With that said `export {a, b, c}` just exports three things, not an object containing these three things. This is because if you also have `export const d = 4` you're not exporting *four* things from the module. The `export` statement *adds* to the exported bindings, since each module can export many things.

Comment: Damn it "you're not exporting" should say "you're **now** exporting". One of the worst typos to have - flipping the entire thing you wanted to say....

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry but I don't quite understand. I thought exporting multiple functions was the way to go, as it allows webpack to see if code has been imported or not. I'm sorry I forgot to mention that I'm using webpack to bundle my code

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```html
<select id="create-PO">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="la">LA</option>
  <option value="nyc">NYC</option>
</select>

<div id="la" class="create-PO-location">
  West Coast
</div>

<div id="nyc" class="create-PO-location">
  East Coast
</div>
```

JS

```js
export function dropDown1(){
 $(".create-PO-location").hide();
 $("#create-PO").on("click", function() {
   $("#" + $(this).val()).fadeIn(700);
   $("div:not(#" + $(this).val()).hide();
 })
}
```

You want to hide the div by initialization.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for taking the time to answer. Unfortunately, that's not the answer I'm looking for. I already hide the divs via css (to prevent FOUC). My issue is that only one function (whichever is declared first) works. The second one never seems to fire.